# How to select proper consent in azure app registration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

In case of Azure app registration, add a scope, in who can consent; there are two options

"admin & user" and "admin only"

What is the difference between two? which one to choose and when?

Answer (score 0):

> **Scopes are the permissions that a web API exposes for client applications to request access to. Client applications request the user's consent for these scopes when making authentication requests to get tokens to access the web APIs.**

##### Admin Only consent

This consent can only be given by ***Global Administrator***.
Only admin has the permissions to alter the other objects.

When you select **admin-only** consent, it means that only admins can grant the consent for users. Till then, users have to wait for admin's approval.

#### When admin consent is selected, your users will get a message like this:

[image]

#### To grant that consent, admins will get a screen like this:

[image]

##### Admin & user consent

When you select **admin & user consent**, it means that this scope is meant not only for administrators but also for users.

This means there is no need for administrators to grant the consent, the users can consent themselves.

##### When to use and what to use:

Select **Admins only** for higher-privileged permissions to make your application more secure.

Select **Admins & users** if you don't want your users to wait for admin approval.

**Reference:**

[Configuring Scopes in Azure Active Directory (Part 1) - DEV Community](https://dev.to/czmiel24/configuring-scopes-in-azure-active-directory-part-1-3bio)

[Understanding Azure AD application consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/application-consent-experience)